# Encrypt a file with private key so only who owns file knows the content

Tags: encryption, gpg

I'd like to exchange sensitive data between two points, without anyone knowing the files contents. (ISP, Admins, etc) no one but who holds the private key.

A command line solution would be great. We both have the private key on our machines already created locally exchanged in person not over the internet.

Answer (score 4):

```
gpg --local-user [fingerprint] --recipient [fingerprint] --encrypt-files [anyfile(s)]
```

Note that by default this uses some compression, to disable it altogether, you can start with this:

```
gpg --compress-algo none
```

Additionally, you could prevent users from identifying you by specifying `--throw-keyids`, from man page:

> Do not put the recipient key IDs into encrypted messages. This helps to hide the receivers of the message and is a limited countermeasure against traffic analysis.2 On the receiving side, it may slow down the decryption process because all available secret keys must be tried.

---

### Conclusion

Turning off compression is especially useful with large files, you could do something like this, which would prove useful on majority systems supporting AES-NI instruction set, encrypted by your key and decryptable only by your key `bash` alias:

```sh
gpg_fingerprint='0000...FFFF'

alias encrypt="gpg \
--compress-algo none \
--cipher-algo aes256 \
--digest-algo sha512 \
--local-user \$gpg_fingerprint \
--recipient \$gpg_fingerprint \
--encrypt-files "
```

Notes:

- This `bash` alias is ready to be written into your `.bash_aliases` file. If you do not have one, create it, to have aliases separated.
- `\$gpg_fingerprint` is not the same as `$gpg_fingerprint`, but depends on your use case, if testing and setting that variable on runtime, use `\$gpg_fingerprint`; on the contrary, if you're done testing, and want to hard-code it, you can use `$gpg_fingerprint`.